# Why game window automatically scale itself when I press play?

Tags: unity

When I am in the editor and I press play to test my game something weird happens,
the game window is like zooming in.. and I am not touching anything, the scale slider just goes from x0.41 to x1.
What may cause the problem? Bug in the editor?

Thank you in advance.

PS:
I noticed that the problem is only with my custom game windows, their initial scale is 0.41 and not 1, why is that?

Comment: Since most of us here aren't on the Unity Engine development team or have insider knowledge of how the editor works under the hood, we might not be able to give you a very satisfying answer. If you feel this is a bug, you could consider [filing a bug report for the Unity development team](https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/bug-reporting)

Comment: Which scale slider are you referring to? What custom game windows are you talking about?

Comment: @Byte56 I am talking about Unity engine, I specified it as a tag.

Comment: I know you're talking about the Unity Engine. I asked which scale slider you're referring to and what custom game windows. I use Unity regularly and I don't know what scale slider there is for a 'custom game window'. Screenshots maybe?

Comment: @Byte56 When you enter your Unity project you see multiple windows, the scene window (or you can call it scene view), the game window, hierarchy, project and the inspector. The game window has this option to resize itself to some build-in sizes (one of them is "free aspect"). Now, there is an option to create a custom size in the end of all the build-in sizes. If I make a new screen size and I choose that screen size I get this problem which automatically when I play the game the game window zooms. Hope I am more clear now than before, thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, that's more clear. I'll take a look this evening when I'm at a computer with Unity.